# How to add verify badge on administrator or customer account In Woocommerce my account?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, customization, verification

I have been trying to add verification badge to Woocommerce My-Account users beside their display name but I no success. I searched the internet but their are no plugins or situations that fill the same case. Please i need to know the code or what plugin or css does it? I uploaded a picture for showing an example. Thank you in advance for helping.

Thats an example how i need the verification beside the displayed name.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF8Ub.jpg)

Comment: You'll have to store some sort of user meta for that user then you'll have to show/hide the badge based on that metadata. I think you'll have to code this on your own, there is a rare chance to find a similar plugin for this request.

Comment: Can you please add the code here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thats the code found it:

```
$user_roles = $current_user->roles;
$user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

    if ($user_role == 'pending') {
    echo '<i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-lg" style="color:#ffa500" ></i>';
    } elseif ($user_role == 'unverified') {
    echo '<i class="fa fa-times-circle-o fa-lg" style="color:#ff0000" ></i>';
    } elseif ($user_role == 'Verified') {
    echo '<i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg" style="color:#1DADFF"></i>';
      } else {
    echo '<strong>' . $user_role . '</strong>';
}
```